# Is the restriction of the dualizing sheaf to an irreducible component the dualizing sheaf of the irreducible component?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Spec}{Spec} \DeclareMathOperator{\hom}{\mathcal{Hom}} \DeclareMathOperator{\ox}{\mathcal{O}_X}$
Let $f:X \to Y$ be a proper morphism. In section 6.4. in Liu's book he introduces the $r$-dualizing sheaf $\omega_f$ for $f$ which satisfies the property 
$$f_*\hom_{\ox}(\mathcal{F},\omega_f) \cong \hom_{\mathcal{O}_Y}(R^rf_* \mathcal{F},\mathcal{O}_Y ).$$

In the special case of $f$ being finite he proves that the 0-dualizing sheaf is given by $f^!\mathcal{O}_Y = \hom_{\mathcal{O}_Y}(f_*\mathcal{O}_X,\mathcal{O}_Y)$ where this is considered an $\mathcal{O}_X$-module via multiplication into the argument.

Let $X$ be a proper, one-dimensional scheme over the field $k$ and let $Y = \mathbb{P}_k^1$. Let $\omega_f$ denote the 0-dualizing sheaf for $f$. Let $Z$ denote an irreducible component of $X$. Let $j: Z \to X$ denote the corresponding closed immersion. Then $f \circ j$ is again finite and we denote its dualizing sheaf by $\omega_{f \circ j}$.

> **My question is:** Is the restriction of $\omega_f$ to $Z$ (via the pullback $j^*$) isomorphic to the 0-dualizing sheaf $\omega_{f \circ j}$ for the morphism $f \circ j$?

I am grateful for any kind of hints or ressources that consider those properties of the dualizing sheaf.

Comment: Did you look in Hartshorne's book "Residue and duality" ?

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet Not until now. Unfortunately, I am not familiar with derived categories. But as far as I can interpret the results from Chapter 3, § 6, we only know that $(f \circ g)^! \cong g^! \circ f^!$ for suitable $f$ and $g$. But for a closed immersion $g$ I cannot find that $g^!$ is the same as $g^*$ (which also looks wrong to me). Do you have any more specific recommendation in that book or another resource? Thank you for your comments!

Comment: $f^! = f^*$ when $f$ is an open immersion (or more generally, they are the same up to a shift if $f$ is a topological submersion, i.e a smooth morphism). I don't know the algebraic side really well but for topological side my reference is Shapira & Kashiwara, Sheaves on manifolds or the book by Dimca "Sheaves in topology".
But I'm not really familiar with derived category of coherent sheaves. Maybe the book of Huybrecht contains useful informations, sorry that I can't answer your question.